# How do you create a vim key mapping that requires numbers before the hotkey (like <G>)?

Tags: vim

I want to create a mapping like the `G` hotkey that jumps to a line (e.g., to jump to line 10: `10G`). How can I do that?

Comment: The G command seems builtin. No need to define a mapping. `10gg` also go to line 10.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can obtain that number from the v:count or v:count1 variable. See

```
:help v:count
```

For example,

```
:map G :<C-U>echo v:count<CR>
```

Comment: Perfect. Got me down the right path. Needed to use `exe` though: `nmap <tab> :<C-U>exe "buffer ".v:count<CR>`

Comment: For anyone wondering why `<C-U>`, because if you use a count before running into command line, vim will insert a range automatically. `<C-U>` is used to clear that range so that we do not run into error when running a command that does not take a range.