# Apply a count to a mapped command

Tags: vim

I want to join every four lines of a file into a single line. I can do this by typing:

```
JJJj
```

Since I am going to do that repeatedly, I mapped it to a key:

```
map <F5> JJJj
```

Now, I can hold down `F5` and it works, but it would take all day long to get through this file that way. Is there a way that I can tell vim to execute `JJJj` multiple times? `100<F5>` did not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you create a vim key mapping that requires numbers before the hotkey (like <G>)?](http://superuser.com/questions/410847/how-do-you-create-a-vim-key-mapping-that-requires-numbers-before-the-hotkey-lik)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for macros:

```
qq
JJJj
q
```

then:

```
100@q
```

or:

```
:%norm! @q
```

But you can also use your mapping with `:normal` too:

```
:%norm <C-v><F5>   <-- press Ctrl+V then F5
```

Comment: I. Must. Proofread. I. Must. Proofread. I. Must. Proofread. I. Must. Proofread. I. Must. Proofread. I. Must. Proofread.